# SSL certificates no longer work with cURL

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, certificate, wsl2

When running the following command on WSL:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh
```

I get the following error:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

This command used to run successfully, but it does not anymore. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611640/curl-60-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top) does not work, no combination of `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt install ca-certificates --reinstall`, or `sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh` works. I have tried numerous solutions online, none of which work. I have tried reinstalling Ubuntu and even installing a different version of Ubuntu, neither of which worked. I am at a loss for what to try at this point.

Comment: Is there any chance that a proxy of some sort is involved (that wasn't before)?

Comment: Come to think of it, this sounds like it might be similar to another question I came across a few months ago.  In that case, attempting `Invoke-WebRequest https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh` from PowerShell showed us that a corporate proxy was actively blocking Github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution! I don't have a full grasp on the issue, but I think it's something along the lines of corporate IT installing some certs onto my Windows machine which didn't automatically transfer over to WSL. Anyways, the issue can be fixed easily with this [powershell script](https://github.com/bayaro/windows-certs-2-wsl).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Well, sort of -- It really sounds like it's the problem I pointed out in the comments.  Your IT department is intercepting TLS traffic and doing deep packet inspection (DPI) on it.  They install certificates (or really a certificate authority) in Windows so that the apps there don't complain about the man-in-the-middle interception, but no, those certs aren't present in WSL, so apps there (rightly) complain that the host key isn't signed by a known CA.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I have same problem, try wsl2 instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -k https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh
```

The `-k` (a.k.a. `--insecure`) will skip TLS certificate verification.